# Boost strength of router using multiple router's network through WAN

Tags: router, dd-wrt, bridge

I have D-Link dir-600 router with dd-wrt firmware.

I have two more APs belonging to my neighbors.

can I use these APs to boost my routers strength over WAN.

I can have physical access to neighbors router.

Comment: So... you want to know if you can steal your neigbours internet and use it with your DD-WRT to make your internet faster?

Comment: No..I have my own hi-speed internet connection..i just want to use their router strength with their permission to increase my coverage area...

Comment: I just want to use router as a repeater...but the router being used as repeater should be capable of doing all its function simultaneously using VPN or anything else..

Comment: how far away are the neighbors? If they're very close I doubt it'd make much difference.

Comment: 2-3 flats apart..

Answer (score 0):

If your neighbour has an *access point* (not a *router*) that they are not using on their network, and that access point is capable of acting as a *wireless range extender*, then yes.  Said access point will only be a range extender for your network and will not be usable on your neighbour's network.

If the neighbour has a router with built-in wireless, then no, you will not be able to do this.

Comment: that means i cannot use a router as range extender while using it as a router with AP...

Comment: That means you can't use a router as a range extender - or at least I don't know of any that offer that functionality.